# Using maven and Tycho p2 extras to make a mirror repository and adding dynamically new repositories and ui

Tags: maven, bamboo, tycho, p2, mirroring

I'm trying to build a mirror repository so I don't depend on external repositories on the web. I know that using tycho extras is really easy to mirror a repository the thing is my plan is to expose a web page where you can add a new repository/repositories and their iu/ius. I'm really stuck thinking how to send all of those parameters (repositories' url and the ius) to reach the backend server (hosted in bamboo) and make a pom using a basic template and adding the information provided by the user and then use maven to make the actual p2 repository. The main goal is to make it repeatable and testable. I'm open for suggestions or ideas.

Here is the pom.xml

```
<build>
   <plugins>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho.extras</groupId>
           <artifactId>tycho-p2-extras-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>${tycho-version}</version>
           <executions>
              <execution>
                  <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>mirror</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <source>
                <!-- source repositories to mirror from -->
                <repository>
                    <url>${repository.url}</url>
                    <layout>${repository.layout}</layout>
                    <!-- supported layouts are "p2-metadata", "p2-artifacts", and "p2" (for joint repositories; default) -->
                </repository>
            </source>
        <!-- starting from here all configuration parameters are optional -->
            <!-- they are only shown here with default values for documentation purpose -->

            <!-- List of IUs to mirror. If omitted, allIUs will be mirrored. -->
            <!-- Omitted IU version element means latest version of the IU -->
            <!-- The destination directory to mirror to. -->
            <destination>${project.build.directory}/repository</destination>
            <!-- Whether only strict dependencies should be followed. -->
            <!-- "strict" means perfect version match -->
            <followStrictOnly>false</followStrictOnly>
            <!-- Whether or not to follow optional requirements. -->
            <includeOptional>true</includeOptional>
            <!-- Whether or not to follow non-greedy requirements. -->
            <includeNonGreedy>true</includeNonGreedy>
            <!-- Filter properties. E.g. filter only one platform -->
            <!-- Whether to filter the resulting set of IUs to only -->
            <!-- include the latest version of each IU -->
            <latestVersionOnly>false</latestVersionOnly>
            <!-- don't mirror artifacts, only metadata -->
            <mirrorMetadataOnly>false</mirrorMetadataOnly>
            <!-- whether to compress the content.xml/artifacts.xml -->
            <compress>true</compress>
            <!-- whether to append to the target repository content -->
            <append>true</append>
            <!-- whether to mirror pack200 artifacts also. Available since tycho-extras 0.17.0 -->
            <includePacked>true</includePacked>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

The problem with this is I can pass by parameter a repository and a layout, but only one repository and one layout, and no ius. I need to parametrize this so I can add multiple repositories, layouts and uis. This should be repeatable for a build server to automatize.

Thank you in advance.
Martin

Comment: This question is a little non-specific at this point.  Can you post a snippet of something you've tried for the problem?  Check out these guidelines - stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I've edited my comment adding my pom.xml so you can have a bit more background to it, there's not much code because i still need to think how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to inject XML snippets the POM via command line properties, so with your current approach you won't in fact get beyond one repository and one IU.

But given that you anyway only want to run this Maven build on a server, you could just generate the pom.xml before starting the build.

Comment: Yeah you are right on that one, now let's suppose I go for that option, any ideas on how to communicate the parameters I need through internet and building the pom dynamically in the build server?

Comment: This is a follow-up question, and I'd never answer a follow-up question asked in a comment. Discouraging follow-up questions is what makes stackoverflow so useful. So ask a new question - but make sure to make the question more specific or it would be down-voted and/or closed.